# Notification service in Android

Tags: android, service, notifications

I'm developing an Android application, i have created one activity that show different messages (like a bacheca) in a listview.

To do this i get data from a database on a server, what that i must do is 
notify the user when a new information is inserted into the database.

Basically I want to pop up a notification on the screen (like when he gets a text message on whatsapp ), when the user presses on the notification initiates the activity containing the news ( bulletin board).

I would like to create a function like that of Facebook, ( I suppose a service ) that monitors the db and when you notice that there is a question notification starts.

How i can do this ?

Comment: for notifications you have to use Google cloud messaging

Comment: It is mandatory to use GCM ?

Comment: no you can use any push notification service

Comment: you talking about popping notification on screen or on the notification tray ?

Comment: I want display a notification on  notification tray when in my db is inserted a new record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [GCM push notification](http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/) Check this tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are talking about is called Push Notification Service. There are many such service providers. One obvious here is Google's GCM. You can also look into Amazon SNS. https://aws.amazon.com/sns/